# Auth0 Login is not working with routing strategy { useHash: true } in Angular 12

Tags: authentication, angular-routing, auth0, angular12

I am trying to integrate Auth0 Login with Microsoft Office Word Add-in, The issue i'm facing is, I've to use
HashLocationStrategy in order to make my routing work in add-in iframe. But it seems like the auth0 login is not working with given routing strategy as it constantly returning false to my 'IsAuthorized$' Observable.

Also, I've checked with given  [auth0-angular-samples-Sample-01](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples/tree/master/Sample-01) auth0 demo on git hub for browser angular application and it seem working fine, But when i tried to apply { useHash: true }  in my routing imports it prevents me from getting authenticated, So Please verify this issue and let us know if there any suggestion and  solution for the same.

For quick review of my demo code, here is the link: [Auth0 sample with HashLocationStrategy](https://ifourtechnolab-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/p/vimal/EkeISMygextIo8DU-TBJ7n8Ber1pkeJcbJc7VTvb50eYmg?e=SvskFk)

Any small help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Same problem here. I've tried it with my own app by removing `useHash: true` from app-routing.module.ts. This seems to allow logging in and proper handling. Once I put back the useHash option it doesn't work anymore.